# How do I display the records the same number of times as their count

Tags: sql, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table

```
date      doctor   patient
20-1-18   xx        11
20-1-18   xx        22
20-1-18   yy        33
21-1-18   zz        44
21-1-18   xx        55
21-1-18   yy        66
22-1-18   zz        77
```

I want to display the doctors who has attended patients more than once in a day. along with the patientname

Expected output

```
date      doctor patient
20-1-18   xx        11
20-1-18   xx        22
```

But I am getting only this

```
date      doctor patient
20-1-18   xx        11
```

How do I make it dislay both the values

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I have shown the table above. Sorry, I had a poor alignment earlier

Comment: @aish . . . Your accepted answer is not valid T-SQL syntax, which is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery with a `having` clause :

```
select *
from tab
where (date, doctor) in
(
  select date, doctor
    from tab
   group by date, doctor
  having count(1)>1
);
+-----------+-------+---------+
|   date    | doctor| patient |
+-----------+-------+---------+
| 2018-01-20|   xx  |    11   |
+-----------+-------+---------+
| 2018-01-20|   xx  |    22   |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/462f0d/1)

Comment: thank you so much, this was simple. Can I know why count(1)? what does count signify. Also what if I have to display doctors who had treated the same patient 2 times in the same day

Comment: You are welcome. Count always needs an argument and as a habit I use "1" as an arbitrary constant, or mostly they use an asterisk as count(*) which I do not suggest because of performance reasons. If you do not look for a specific column as in count(col1), use a constant even if count(1234).  For your last question, you need "select date, doctor, patient from tab group by date, doctor, patient having count(0)=2)

Comment: This will not work in T-SQL.  It will work in standard SQL but it's one of a few places where T-SQL does not support the standrards.

Comment: @Zohar Peled thank you for the info. I wonder what exactly not  supported for T-SQL ?

Comment: In T-Sql, the `IN` operator can take a list of values only on it's right side, not on it's left side.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, this might be the solution:

```
select [date], doctor, patient from (
    select [date], doctor, pateint,
           count(*) over (partition by [date], doctor) cnt
    from my_table
) a where cnt > 1
```

Comment: This is better than `group by` and `having`.

Answer (score 2):

If your dbms didn't support window function you can write a subquery to get `COUNT` by `date,doctor` then `self join`

```
select t2.*
from 
(
SELECT date,doctor,count(*) cn   
FROM T
GROUP BY date,doctor 
) t1 INNER JOIN T t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.doctor = t2.doctor
WHERE cn > 1
```

[sqlifddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/897691/2)

**[Results]**:

```
|    date | doctor | patient |
|---------|--------|---------|
| 20-1-18 |     xx |      11 |
| 20-1-18 |     xx |      22 |
```